# Text boxes are superimposed over each other, and shouldn't be

Tags: textpos

I'm making a planning book for teachers' lesson plans. So I want a series of two-page spreads. So far I have the following:

```
\documentclass[letter,openleft,twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage[left=0pt,right=0pt,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{forloop}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}


\setlength{\TPHorizModule}{1cm}
\setlength{\TPVertModule}{1cm}


\fancypagestyle{mypagestyle}{%
  \fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
  \fancyhead[OC]{}% Author on Odd page, Centred
  \fancyhead[EC]{Week of \makebox[2in]{\dotfill} to \makebox[2in]{\dotfill}}% Title on Even page, Centred
  \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% Header rule of .4pt
}
\pagestyle{mypagestyle}

\newcommand{\aline}{\\\hline &&&&&&\rule{0cm}{5cm}}
\newcounter{theyflines}
%\pagestyle{empty}
\parindent=0pt

\newcommand{\apage}{

\begin{textblock}{21.59}(0,3)
\adjustbox{clip=true,trim=0pt 0pt {\textwidth} 0pt}{\usebox\tempbox}
\end{textblock}
\pagebreak\vspace*{\fill}%
\begin{textblock}{21.59}(0,3)
\adjustbox{clip=true,trim={\textwidth} 0pt 0pt 0pt}{\usebox\tempbox}
\end{textblock}
}


\newcounter{theyfpages}

\newsavebox{\tempbox}
\newlength{\pwidth}
\newlength{\spwidth}

\setlength{\pwidth}{\dimexpr \textwidth-6\tabcolsep-4\arrayrulewidth}%
\divide\pwidth by 3
\setlength{\spwidth}{\dimexpr \pwidth-2cm-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth}%

\savebox{\tempbox}{% fit 3 columns into \textwidth
\begin{tabular}{p{2cm}|p{\spwidth}|p{\pwidth}|p{\pwidth}|p{\pwidth}|p{\pwidth}|p{\pwidth}|}
\hline
Course & Weekly goal & Monday & Tuesday & Wednesday & Thursday & Friday
\forloop{theyflines}{1}{\value{theyflines} < 5}{\aline}\\
\hline
&&&&&&\rule{0cm}{2cm}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}}

\begin{document}

\null\newpage

\forloop{theyfpages}{1}{\value{theyfpages} < 41}{\apage}

\end{document}
```

This is the result:
[image]

As you can see, the two `adjustbox`es are superimposed on top of each other, on both the left and right pages. I suspect `textpos` has something to do with it because the problem appeared after I started using the `textbox` environment to make the two halves of the spread line up. How can I remove the superimposed tabular material?